# Can we become God?

Tags: belief, scripture, gods, moksha, vedanta

Can we become God?

Most people believe that the Gods that we are worshipping are fixed and no human can reach the state of God. Is this true?

If a person is born and lives as the purest one and when he attains the state as God, can he be included in the Gods of today?

Can a person become God if he learns all the things that a God knows?

Comment: You can certainly attain God in your lifetime.So in a way you can become God but not in the literal sense.

Comment: @Rickross Hi Rickross.My question is that if I try to become God. Can I?. Is there any path?

Comment: Gods are different entities so to speak. .You can not become God but yes you can attain him

Comment: @Rickross I don't intent to hurt anyone. Let have Modi as Prime minister for 5 years and people seems to have a new PM even so he is good.Time can change anything.If I like to have a new one instead of Vishnu or Shiva who may has the capability for that place like Shiva or Vishnu.

Comment: You can not have any replacement for Bhagawan.By doing holy works and thereby earning sufficient punya what you can atmost achieve is a post like Demi God Indra in a new birth.But even that is not possible in your present lifetime.

Comment: Related [Are we really God?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4052/3500)

Comment: According to  Advaita, when you free yourself from Maya, your Atman becomes same as Brahman.

Comment: @AnilKumar Atman doesn't become same as Brahman because it is always Brahman.

Comment: Yet great saints said we all are God

Comment: You can never BECOME God. God is who You are! There is no need to become something you already are. However becoming God is not about knowing everything or getting super powers. God is Love as you already Know. Being God is all about Loving Yourself (If you love yourself, you will love all), unconditionally and absolute. That is Being God! Self realization burns away all desires, for you realize that all that has been created, is actually just Yourself! All the best. Good question.

Comment: God is residing in all. You are yantra your physical body is mantra and your heart is tantra----kánchi paramacharya's golden words---self realisation--do this----why you are born? What is the purpose of your birth? What you have achieved so far? I leave it to you after ascertaining the three you can come to a conclusion about becoming a God.

Comment: “Each soul is *potentially divine*. The goal is to manifest this divinity by controlling nature, external and internal. Do this either by work, or worship, or psychic control, or philosophy - by one, or more, or all of these - and be free. This is the whole (*essence* ..addition is mine) of religion. Doctrines, or dogmas, or rituals, or books, or temples, or forms, are but secondary details.    *Swami Vivekananda*

Comment: its joking only india people think the unthinkable becoming God, he himself is God, after seeing this whole world, its creation, its uniquness, how everything rythmic, how its managed.. Suppose one thinks he is god, Can he not die in his own lifetime can he not afflicted by illness.. this just mind baffling that with all limitation of the body this stupid that im god is popping up to the mind and corrupting everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. "brahma vid brahmaiva bhavati". One who knows brahman becomes brahman himself.

The path to know brahman is yoga - any (or a combination) of bhakti/gnyana/karma (upasana)/raja yogas.

> स यो ह वै तत् परमं **ब्रह्म वेद ब्रह्मैव भवति** नास्याब्रह्मवित्कुले भवति । 
>   तरति शोकं तरति पाप्मानं गुहाग्रन्थिभ्यो विमुक्तोऽमृतो भवति ॥ ९ ॥
>
> sa yo ha vai tat paramaṃ **brahma veda brahmaiva bhavati** nāsyābrahmavitkule bhavati | 
>   tarati śokaṃ tarati pāpmānaṃ guhāgranthibhyo vimukto'mṛto bhavati || 9 ||
>
> 9. **He who knows that highest Brahman becomes even Brahman**; and in his line, none who knows not the Brahman will be born. He crosses grief and virtue and vice and being freed from the knot of the heart, becomes immortal.
>
> [*Mundaka Upanishad 3.2.9*](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mundaka-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145141.html)

Comment: Excellent my friend.As Swami Vivekananda said " Believe Yourself.You will become what you wish to be".God is Love.If we love all then we all are God

Comment: This is by way of speaking. You cannot ofcourse become the souce of all jiva atma's.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**. One can become Brahman.

As stated by Lord Krishna in Bhagvad Geeta,

> मां च योऽव्यभिचारेण भक्ति-योगेन सेवते।
> स गुणान्समतीत्यैतान् **ब्रह्मभूयाय कल्पते**।। ([14.26](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-14-26/))
>
> One who engages in full devotional service, unfailing in all circumstances, at once transcends the modes of material nature and thus **comes to the level of Brahman.**

[**How one can become Brahman?**](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-14-22-25/)

> प्रकाशं च प्रवृत्तिं च मोहमेव च पाण्डव।
> न द्वेष्टि सम्प्रवृत्तानि न निवृत्तानि काङ्क्षति।। (14.22)
>
> उदासीनवदासीनो गुणैर्यो न विचाल्यते।
> गुणा वर्तन्त इत्येव योऽवतिष्ठति नेङ्गते।। (14.23)
>
> समदुःखसुखः स्वस्थः समलोष्टाश्मकाञ्चनः।
> तुल्यप्रियाप्रियो धीरस्तुल्यनिन्दात्मसंस्तुतिः।। (14.24)
>
> मानापमानयोस्तुल्यस्तुल्यो मित्रारिपक्षयोः।
> सर्वारम्भपरित्यागी गुणातीतः स उच्यते।। (14.25)
>
> O son of Pandu, he who does not hate illumination, attachment and delusion when they are present or long for them when they disappear; who is unwavering and undisturbed through all these reactions of the material qualities, remaining neutral and transcendental, knowing that the modes alone are active; who is situated in the self and regards alike happiness and distress; who looks upon a lump of earth, a stone and a piece of gold with an equal eye; who is equal toward the desirable and the undesirable; who is steady, situated equally well in praise and blame, honor and dishonor; who treats alike both friend and enemy; and who has renounced all material activities—such a person is said to have transcended the modes of nature.

In short, the one who is neutral in all the opposites (honor-dishonor, friend-enemy, desirable-undesirable etc) i.e., one who transcends all three Gunas can become Brahman who is Ultimate Reality.

Apart from the Supreme Brahman, **one can become Lord Indra** by performing [hundred Ashwamedha Yagnas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/619/what-is-the-significance-of-ashwamedha-yagna).

> If a person is born and lives as the purest one and when he attains the state as God, can he be included in the Gods of today?

Yes, he is included in the Gods. For example, the story of present Purandhara Indra who became Indra by performing yagnas is discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7234/story-of-purandara-indra).

Comment: engages in full devotional service > that's not the only condition to attain Brahman. Brahman is always there, obscured by the veil of samsara and the ego. Through enlightenment and understanding too they may reach the same conclusion.

Answer (score 5):

No, we can never become God.

> Who is Ishvara? Janmadyasya yatah - "From whom is the birth,
>   continuation, and dissolution of the universe," - He is Ishvara - "the
>   Eternal, the Pure, the Ever-Free, the Almighty, the All-Knowing, the
>   All-Merciful, the Teacher of all teachers"; and above all, Sa Ishvarah
>   anirvachaniya-premasvarupah - "He the Lord is, of His own nature,
>   inexpressible Love." These certainly are the definitions of a Personal
>   God. Are there then two Gods - the "Not this, not this," the
>   Sat-chit-ananda, the Existence-knowledge-Bliss of the philosopher, and
>   this God of love of the Bhakta? No it is the same Sat-chit-Ananda who
>   is also the God of Love, the impersonal and personal in one. It has
>   always to be understood that the Personal God worshipped by the Bhakta
>   is not separate or different from Brahman. All is Brahman, the One
>   without a second; only the Brahman, as unity or absolute, is too much
>   of an abstraction to be loved and worshipped; so the Bhakta chooses
>   the relative aspect of Brahman, that is Ishvara, the Supreme Ruler.
>   **To use a simile: Brahman is as the clay or substance out of which an infinite variety of articles are fashioned. As clay, they are all one;
>   but form or manifestation differentiates them. Before everyone of them
>   was made, they all existed potentially in the clay, and, of course,
>   they are identical substantially; but when formed, and so long as the
>   form remains, they are separate and different; the clay-mouse can
>   never become a clay-elephant, because, as manifestations, form alone
>   makes them what they are, though as unformed clay they are all one.**
>   Ishvara is the highest manifestation of the Absolute Reality, or in
>   other words, the highest possible reading of the Absolute by the human
>   mind. Creation is eternal and so also is Ishvara........Those who
>   attain to that state where there is neither knower, nor knowable, nor
>   knowledge, where there is neither I, nor thou, nor he, where there is
>   neither subject, nor object, nor relation, "there, who is seen by
>   whom?" - such persons have gone beyond everything to "where words
>   cannot go nor mind", gone to where the Shrutis declare as "Not this,
>   not this"; but for those who cannot, or will not reach this state,
>   there will inevitably remain the triune vision of the one
>   undifferentiated Brahman as nature, soul and the interpenetrating
>   sustainer of both - Ishvara. ..... Bhakti, then, can be directed
>   towards Brahman, only in His personal aspect. "The way is more
>   difficult for those whose mind is attached to the absolute!" Bhakti
>   has to float on smoothly with the current of our nature. True it is
>   that we cannot have any idea of the Brahman which is not
>   anthropomorphic, but is it not equally true of everything we know? The
>   greatest psychologist the world has ever known, Bhagavan Kapila,
>   demonstrated ages ago that human consciousness is one of the elements
>   in the make-up of all the objects of our perception and conception,
>   internal as well as external. Beginning with our bodies and going up
>   to Ishvara, we may see that every object of our perception is this
>   consciousness plus something else, whatever that may be; and this
>   unavoidable mixture is what we ordinarily think of as reality. Indeed
>   it is, and ever will be, all of the reality that is possible for human
>   mind to know. Therefore to say that Ishvara is unreal, because He is
>   anthropomorphic is sheer nonsense. It sounds very much like the
>   occidental squabble on idealism and realism, which fearful-looking
>   quarrel has for its foundation a mere play on the word "real". The
>   idea of Ishvara covers all the ground ever denoted and connoted by the
>   word real, and Ishvara is as real as anything else in the universe;
>   and after all, the word real means nothing more than what has now been
>   pointed out. Such is our philosophical conception of Ishvara.
>   (Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda III.37-42)

Answer (score 1):

It is question often arising even in modern times.  Swami Vivekananda supplies a sufficiently modern answer:

*“**Each soul is potentially divine**. The goal is to manifest this divinity by controlling nature, external and internal. Do this either by work, or worship, or psychic control, or philosophy - by one, or more, or all of these - and be free. This is the whole of religion. Doctrines, or dogmas, or rituals, or books, or temples, or forms, are all but secondary details."*

The precept is very ancient... given out in English (language of this site) after Swami's visit to US.

Answer (score 1):

**No, that is NOT possible.**

No one can become Ishvara ( God) as God is only ONE. It is not correct to translate God as the Formless All-pervading Brahman, as Adi Shankaracharya says that even the Brahmavid can NOT become Ishvara, Who is the controller of the Universe.

From Gita:

> 18.61 O Arjuna, Isvara resides in the region of the heart of all creatures, revolving through Maya all the creatures (as though) mounted on a machine!

Isvara is NOT some deathless human being living at a particular place. He is dwelling in each being.

So answers to the question is : NO

Answer (score 1):

If you can perform sarvamedha or purushmedha you can become Brahman or something close to it.

[What are the similarities and differences between Purushamedha Yagna and Sarvamedha Yagna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21968/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-purushamedha-yagna-and-sarvame)

Narayana was only a rishi (i.e., a human) in Rig Veda and became the supreme being after performimg purushamedha.

> Purusha Nârâyana desired, 'Would that I overpassed all beings! would that I alone were everything here (this universe)!' He beheld this five-days’ sacrificial performance, the Purushamedha, and took it , and performed offering therewith; and having performed offering therewith, he overpassed all beings, and became everything here. And, verily, he who, knowing this, performs the Purushamedha, or who even knows this, overpasses all beings, and becomes everything here.

We don't know if Purushamedha/Sarvamedha can be performed any more.

Answer (score -1):

Understand first what do u mean by god ? is it oneness u r seeking ? or
a powerful being who can do anything with the flick of the hand.
I believe we can be both but not at a time. seeking "the light" means being brahman; without guilt, the desire of materials. U r already GOD ( part of him) , u just need to realize it. medidate unless u see the while light nd feel peacefull.

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Although you have tried to give answer to the question by your way , the answers on this site should be provided with citing of sources from authentic sources like Bhagavad Gita , Upanishads etc. Pls. add sources in your answer. "U r already GOD ( part of him) " you can quote  respective upanishad verses for your this sentence also.

Answer (score -1):

Lord May be realized on different levels. As Bhagavatam States [here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/2/11)

> Learned transcendentalists who know the Absolute Truth call this
>   nondual substance Brahman, Paramātmā or Bhagavān.

Just like Sun and Sunshine. There are three features viz, Sunshine(Brahman), Sun Globe(Paramatma), Sun Deity Vivasvan(Bhagvana or personal feature).

There are different philosophies that subscribe to Vedanta school, Viz Advaita, VishishtAdvaita, Dvaita and so on as described in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/dvaita-vs-advaita-vs-vishistadvaita-vs-shuddhadvaita-vs-any-other)

Now different philosophies have different opinions as to three levels of God realization. I.e Advaita says that Brahman realization is highest where as there are other schools(Vaishnava) who believe that associating with God in His personal form is superior i.e. Realization of Bhagavan feature is highest.

As per Advaita **YOU ARE GOD**. So no question of becoming God, of course you have forgotten or due to Avidya you perceive the individuality.

Now as I have mentioned the sun example, You may merge into sunshine but you can never become one with the King of Sun planet. 
That is in Advaita terms you can never become a Saguna Brahman(refer this answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14114/how-does-adishankaracharya-advaita-explain-concept-of-avatar)).

Also in Vedanta sutra and Gita it is mentioned that we are part and parcel of One Supreme God. **We are not one with Him**.
But we are one in quality with Him. Just like Sunshine is one in quality with Sun but Sunshine is not Sun.