# Do scriptures specify how animals should be killed during the sacrifice?

Tags: scripture, animals, sacrifice

I think the horse in the Ashwamedha was killed with knives.  The Somavajapeya involves suffocating the sacrificial animal if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Do you mean what tools were used to kill the animals?

Comment: At first please provide some references/basis to your claims/thinking

Answer (score 2):

> Do scriptures specify how animals should be killed during the sacrifice?

**Yes, the horse in the Ashwamedha is suffocated with a cloth.**

Taittiriya Brahmana 3.9.20:

> tArpyeNAshvam samjnapayanti | yajno vai tArpyam | yajnenaivainam samardhayanti | yAmena samnA prastotA'nUpatiSThate | yamalokam evainam gamayati
>
> **They (the Samitars, the slaughterers) kill the horse (literally: cause the horse to *acquiesce*) by means of the tArpya cloth.** The tArpya cloth surely is the sacrifice. They thus abundantly provide him with (the essence of) the sacrifice. The Prastotar worships (the horse) by singing the Saman that belongs to Yama. **He thus sends him to Yama loka.**

As you can see, they really kill a real horse and it's not some metaphorical description. The reference to Yama loka proves this. The soul of the horse goes to the world (loka) of Yama, who is the god of death. There is no reason to interpret these words metaphorically.

Comment: "As you can see, they really kill a real horse and it's not some metaphorical description." - this is not what was asked in the question. Seems like you added this to counter the other answer. You need to mark this line in bold: "They (the Samitars, the slaughterers) kill the horse (literally: cause the horse to acquiesce) by means of the tArpya cloth."

Answer (score 2):

No, ***vedas do not mention killing of animals during sacrifice.***

Brahmana texts & shrauta sutra texts on Ashwamedha Yagya only mention presence of knife during ritual, nowhere do they mention usage of knife for killing the animal.

***Killing of animal is only symbolic as described by satapatha brahmana 3.8.1.15:***

> *atha punaretyāhavanīyamabhyāvṛtyāsate | nedasya saṃjñapyamānasyādhyakṣā asāmeti tasya na kūṭena praghnanti mānuṣaṃ hi
> tanno eva paścātkarṇam pitṛdevatyaṃ hi **tadapigṛhya vaiva mukhaṃ
> tamayanti** veṣkaṃ vā kurvanti tannāha jahi mārayeti mānuṣaṃ hi
> tatsaṃjñapayānvaganniti taddhi devatrā sa yadāhānvagannityetarhi hyeṣa
> devānanugacati tasmādāhānvaganniti*
>
> *15. They then step back (to the altar) and sit down turning towards the Ahavaniya, “lest they should be eye-witnesses to its being quieted
> (strangled).” They do not slay it on the frontal bone, for that is
> human manner; nor behind the ear, for that is after the manner of the
> Fathers. **They either choke it by merely keeping its
> mouth closed, or they make a noose.** Therefore he says not, “Slay!
> kill!” for that is human manner, but, **“Quiet it! It has passed
> away!”** for that is after the manner of the gods. For when he says,
> “It has passed away,” then this one (the Sacrificer) passes away to
> the gods: therefore he says, “It has passed away.”*

From above verses it can be seen that it is the mouth (mukham) of the animal that is covered with a cloth or noose. Now an animal dies of suffocation only when its nose is closed. Closing the mouth of the animal will not suffocate animal, it only chokes the voice of animal resulting in little or no sound leading to quieting of animal. This is what is referred in above verses as symbolic killing.

So wherever vedas say kill the animals it means quieting the animal.

***mahAbhArata ashwamedha parva XCI condemns killing of animals during animal sacrifice rituals i.e. literal interpretation of killing in vedic texts :***

> Formerly, on one occasion Sakra performed a particular sacrifice.
> While the limbs of the sacrifice were spread out, the Ritwijas became
> busy in accomplishing the diverse rites ordained in the scriptures.
> The pourer of libations, possessed of every qualification, became
> engaged in pouring libations of clarified butter. The great Rishis
> were seated around. The deities were summoned one by one by contented
> Brahmanas of great learning uttering scriptural Mantras in sweet
> voices. Those foremost of Adhwaryyus, not fatigued with what they did,
> recited the Mantras of the Yajurveda in soft accents. **The time came
> for slaughtering the animals. When the animals selected for sacrifice
> were seized, the great Rishis, O king, felt compassion for them.
> Beholding that the animals had all become cheerless, those Rishis,
> endued with wealth of penances, approached Sakra and said unto him,
> 'This method of sacrifice is not auspicious.** Desirous of acquiring
> great merit as thou art, this is verily an indication of thy
> unacquaintance with sacrifice. O Purandara, **animals have not been
> ordained to be slaughtered in sacrifices**. O puissant one, these
> preparations of thine are destructive of merit. **This sacrifice is
> not consistent with righteousness**. **The destruction of creatures
> can never be said to be an act of righteousness.**

***mahAbhArata shAntI parva CCCXXXVII gives an example of ashwamedha where animals were not slain:***

> *King Uparichara, otherwise called Vasu, became a disciple of Vrihaspati and soon became the foremost of his disciples. Admitted as
> such, he began to study at the feet of his preceptor that science
> which was composed by the seven Rishis who were (otherwise) known by
> the name of Chitrasikhandins. With soul cleansed from all sorts of
> evil by sacrifices and other religious rites, he ruled the Earth like
> Indra ruling the Heaven. **The illustrious king performed a great
> Horse-sacrifice** in which his preceptor Vrihaspati became the Hota.
> The sons of Prajapati (Brahman) themselves, viz., Ekata, Dwita, and
> Trita, became the Sadasyas in that sacrifice. 2 There were others also
> who became Sadasyas in that sacrifice, viz., Dhanusha, Raivya,
> Arvavasu, Parvavasu, the Rishi Medhatithi, the great Rishi Tandya, the
> blessed Rishi Santi, otherwise called Vedasiras, the foremost of
> Rishis, viz., Kapila, who was the father of Salihotra, the first
> Kalpa, Tittiri the elder brother of Vaisampayana, Kanwa, and
> Devahotra, in all forming sixteen. In that great sacrifice, O monarch,
> all the requisite articles were collected. **No animals were slain in
> it.** **The king had ordained it so. He was full of compassion.** Of
> pure and liberal mind, he had cast off all desires, and was
> well-conversant with all rites.*

Comment: Thx for posting this @ArvindC I went vegan because of concern for animals years ago. Animal sacrifice tradition is one of the things I’ve struggled with as I’ve just started down Devi bhakti path. I carry out all my puja rituals with almond milk and vegan milks/butter etc because I feel so strongly against exploitation of animals. I’m against factory farming, I’m against zoos and circuses w/ animals also. So reading your reply here today is so great ! Excellent. Thx :)

Comment: @devibhakt thank you

Comment: Fully agree with both, thx for writing those replies ! Along with the enormous interpolation issue of all kinds of ignorant people contributing their not great ideas over centuries, I’ve often wondered how many things have also just been misunderstood due to poor translations from Sanskrit. Taking things literally that were meant figuratively, etc. Then you end up with all sorts of ridiculous practices and notions that were not actually meant that way at all. But we can fix it now, I think, or at least try :D

Answer (score 0):

The Kings does Ashwamedha Yagya and after that they release that Horse, and till where the Horse goes that land is claimed by the King if anyone opposed he has to fight with the Army of the King who did Ashwamedha Yagya.

the translation of the word 'medha' is often not interpreted as sacrifice. There are words like 'purushamedha' and 'sarvamedha'. Sarvamedha definitely doesn't mean sacrificing everyone.

Please see the second answer of this question, which is very correct and it related directly to Dharm.

[What is the significance of Ashwamedha Yagna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/619/what-is-the-significance-of-ashwamedha-yagna?rq=1)

[image: More on similar lines]

[image: Please see more details on why Ashwamedha does not mean killing]

You can take a look at this link on Google Books.

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=iYMwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41&dq=medha+does+not+mean+killing&source=bl&ots=vTqm_imTMe&sig=Il9hP0X47tph7DWOA2VkQRb4rIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXgu296_7aAhXBebwKHddvBScQ6AEIYDAJ#v=onepage&q=medha%20does%20not%20mean%20killing&f=false

Comment: Its not true.... https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8882/7853 goat and other animals are used in yajnas...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi This text you are linking is by Max Muller, who has does more harm than another person to break the Strong roots of Dharm in our country. The Aryan Invasion theory was highly debunked again and again.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Also Max Muller converted a commentaries on Vedas by Sayana Acharya, so he selected the highly controversial commentary available at that time. If you have really any will to know about our culture, I will request you to read " Satyarth Prakash "

Comment: i am not the one who wrote those texts but i am familiar with arya samaj texts. But even many vedangas like shrauta and grhya sutras talk of animal related stuff. Ramayana also has such mention. You can discuss more in chat room on this subject.

Comment: Please don't say you are aware about  arya samaj text, If you were you would never fall in Max Muller Trap and I hope you do not believe in Aryan Invasion theory as well. Yes scriptures would talk about animal related stuff. Yes Ramayana also has such mention but it was in order to complete the incidents and relate one incident to the another, I am a new user and thus does not have privilege for chat room and in order to get that privilege I to have answer as per Max Muller and many other western sources which do not understand the fundamental of Dharma.

Comment: These are the people who studied the texts, however without practice of Hinduism and Dharma, these texts would have no understanding of the inner meanings of the Topics and Dharma. I see you have lot of enthusiasm about Hinduism and you are dedicated to learn and understand. I hope and believe you will spread the right message. Its not about the literal meaning but about the intent. You seems smart enough to understand what I mean.

Comment: the problem with arya samaji is that they are very aggressive and do not consider anyone else. Many shrauta and grhya sutra describe animals for sacrifice. In case you don't know what are these then they are vedic manuals for ritusls.

Answer (score -1):

There is no animal sacrifice in Vedas. Some indologists have put the law of sacrificing animals in Vedas by wrong translations. In reality, animal sacrifice in yajnas is prohibited.

First of all, the synonym of Yajna used in Vedas is ‘Adhvara’ which means ‘non-killing”. **Nirukta 1.8 says ‘dhvar’ means kill, and ‘Adhvara’ denotes the negation of killing (which is non killing).**

[image]

I find plenty of Vedic verses which calls ‘Yajna’ as ‘Adhvar’ (means Non-killing), example of such verses are: Atharva Veda 1.4.1, Atharva Veda 3.16.6, Atharva Veda 5.27.8, Rigveda 3.10.7, Rigveda 3.16.6, Rigveda 4.6.1, Rigveda 5.49.4, Rigveda 1.74.4 Yajurveda 1.24, Yajurveda 3.11 etc.

> Mahabharat, Shantiparv 265.9 “**Liquors, fish, mead, meat, rice cooked with sesamum seeds- all these have been inserted into Yajna by the wicked people**. Vedas have not prescribed their use in Yajnas”.
>
> Lord Krishna in Srimad Bhagvatam 11.21.30 says, “People who find enjoyment in violence, out of wickedness and for gratification of their pleasure they slaughter animals, offer the meat in Yajan’s….”

So animal slaughter is completely prohibited.

Comment: From [Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga14/bala_14_frame.htm): "Then the priest, one with controlled senses and rich in scriptural wealth, took up the omentum [fat] of the horse and cooked it as per scriptures while dropping into the altar of fire to bake as a food to the celestials. [1-14-36]....Those remaining body parts that horse are there, the sixteen officiating priests have procedurally oblated all of them into fire. [1-14-38]"

Comment: Commentary on the same site says: "Many animals are sacrificed in Horse ritual. But they will be segregated as forest animals and village animals. In them many of the forest animals will be let off by taking them round the fire on to their right in salutation to fire, agnipradakShiNa-namaskaara. The animals pertaining to village will be sacrificed in ritual. Hence it is up to the priests to decide which is to be retained or let off."

Comment: @sv Read Gita press translation

Comment: Gita Press translation of Valmiki Ramayana says Rama and Lakshmana did not eat meat. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37094/2995) post. So, how can you trust their translations?

Comment: @sv Rama and lakshmana were pure vegetarian. I provided an answer on that post but some people like you hided it.

Comment: @sv In Shatpath brahman, it is written that ashwa is used for kingdom. Medha means increasing so the entire word mean increasing of kingdom

Comment: Nobody hid your other answer. It [says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouHwo.png) you deleted it yourself. Not sure why you deleted it. The system hides all deleted answers from low-rep users.

Comment: 'Rama and Lakshmana were pure vegetarian' - not true, there are dozens of places in Ramayana where they hunt and eat deer. Even [Ramcharitmanas](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n219) says they ate meat.

Comment: @sv If you still believe that animal sacrifice was practiced in yajna, then tell me why above scriptures quoted by me prohibits it?

Comment: @sv Lord ram clearly said that he will not eat meat. Read the answer.

Comment: @sv how can you trust a scripture written during Mughal period while ram was of treta yug.

Comment: @sv If you still have doubt, I can give you my what's app no. So your doubts can be cleared.

Comment: "If you still believe that animal sacrifice was practiced in yajna, then tell me why above scriptures quoted by me prohibits it?" - the answer is simple: Different scriptures were written by different people, those who supported animal sacrifices wrote in its favor others who wanted to promote vegetarianism rejected animal sacrifices. Also, why are you quoting from Shanti Parva of Mahabharata and Bhagavatam if you think they too are written during Mughal period? If all scriptures are corrupted by Mughals and the British then why are are you cherry-picking from them when it supports your view?

Comment: "Lord ram clearly said that he will not eat meat. Read the answer." - I already read it. BTW, you should undelete your answer. How much of Valmiki Ramayana have you read to determine Rama never ate meat? Read [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26284/2995) answer where Rama himself says hunting deer is ok for both sport and also its meat.

Comment: @sv First of all I am not saying that scriptures were coruppted by mughals. Mahabharata was written by vyasa who was present during Mahabharata. Similarly ramayana was written by valmiki in treta yug when ram was there. But Ram was of treta yug and tulsidas was of of 15th century. How can you trust on this type of book.

Comment: @sv The verse you quoted says that Kings hunt the animal for flesh. I accept this thing. Many Kings and people were indulged in this thing but not Lord Ram. Ram killed that deer because he knew that he is maricha. Valmiki Ramayana  3:43:40