# What are the fruits received by performing an Ashwamedha?

Tags: sin, yajna, vedic-rituals, ashwamedha

Ashwamedha is a Vedic yajna done mainly by Kshatriyas and is supposed to have wondrous benefits including getting rid of Brahmahatya and attaining the post of Indra, if 100 of them are performed.

I would like a Phala Shruti discussing all or a majority of the benefits (including sins gotten rid off) accruing by performing this yajna and *how many are required to accomplish that particular fruit* (eg. 100 Ashwamedha gives Indra’s post) **with special focus on the Brahmahatya and sin aspect.**

Rather than a single reference like xyz rishi advised xyz puranic character that Ashwamedha releases Brahmahatya, etc. hence that’s the benefit; It would be preferable to have a compendium list of most/ all the benefits **special focus on the Brahmahatya one alongwith the number of Yajnas to be performed to get rid of the Brahmahatya sin.**

---

Note - Not duplicate of:-

1. [What is the significance of performing Ashwamedha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/619/what-is-the-significance-of-ashwamedha-yagna)
2. [How to remove Brahmahatya sin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11344/how-to-remove-bramhahatya-sin) - which asks for alternatives instead of performing the Yajna.